# How do I edit my xaml code to show the product card like shown in the desired view pic?

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin.forms

Current code thats display the current view. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout Spacing="5"
                                     Padding="10"
                                     Margin="15,0,15,0"
                                     Orientation="Vertical" 

                                     >

                            <Frame Padding="0"
                                   CornerRadius="30"
                                   IsClippedToBounds="True"
                                   HeightRequest="200"
                                   WidthRequest="200"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                                >
                                <Image Aspect="Fill"
                                   HeightRequest="200"
                                   WidthRequest="200"
                                   Source="{Binding pictureUrl}"/>
                            </Frame>

                            <Label TextColor="#000000"
                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                   Text="{Binding name}"/>
                            <Label TextColor="#ff5e14"
                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                   Text="{Binding price ,StringFormat='ZAR {0}'}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

Current view
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wx0V8.png)

desired view
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5YFL.png)

Comment: to start with, the Frame should contain all the elements, not just the Image.  And you should remove the rounded corners from the frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edit your code like following code.

```
 <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"  ItemsLayout="VerticalList">

            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout 
                        
                        HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                                     Padding="20,10,20,10"
                                    >
                    <Frame
                       
                       
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                        
                        Padding="0"
                        CornerRadius="2"
                        HasShadow="True"
                        >
                            <StackLayout 
                                      Padding="0"
                                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                  
                                     
                                         >

                                <Frame Padding="0"
                              
                                   HeightRequest="200"
                                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                    >
                                    <Image Aspect="Fill"
                                       Source="{Binding pictureUrl}"/>
                                </Frame>

                                <Label TextColor="#000000"
                                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                       Text="{Binding name}"/>
                                <Label TextColor="#ff5e14"
                                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                       Text="{Binding price ,StringFormat='ZAR {0}'}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

Here is running screenshot.

[image]